# Scrapy: origin not supplied or is not allowed by this service

Tags: json, ajax, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, scrapy

So I try to crawl a product's rating on target, and it uses ajax. I find out the URL for the XHR is:
http://tws.target.com/productservice/services/reviews/v1/reviewstats/21499594

Now is the part confuses me:
1. If I go to target.com, search for that specific product, open it, then go to the URL mentioned above, I can see the json file in my browser 
2. But if I just directly type in the URL in my browser, I get an error message saying "origin not supplied or is not allowed by this service."

so what is the cause and how can I solve this?
thank you!
(I am using scrapy by the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out a solution that works, but if someone can tell me the underlying mechanism that would be fantastic:)

So in my request, I add a headers saying I am coming from target.com ('Origin': 'http://www.target.com'), then everything works

```
head = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                  '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36',
                'Origin': 'http://www.target.com'
       }

jsoncontent = requests.get(url, headers=head).content
jsdict = json.loads(jsoncontent)
```